# RPG - IBM i TimeStamp format

Tags: server, timestamp, ibm-midrange, rpg

I'm working on an IDE (CA Plex) which doesn't support TimeStamp format but ironically it works with an IBM i server (AS400) which works with TimeStamps with the following format: yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss.mmmsss

I'm using a RPG function which calculates the difference between two TimeStamps as the code shows:

```
  *  Difference between two TimeStamps in ms
  /FREE
   &(3:) = %DIFF (&(1:): &(2:): *MSECONDS);
  /END-FREE
```

`&(1:)`, `&(2:)` and `&(3:)` are the parameters sent by the IDE which are incompatible with the function. The TimeStamp format sent is the same I explained before, but RPG compiler doesn't recognize them as TimeStamp. How can I format those parameters? Somethink like this is what I need:

```
tstampone = %timestamp(&(1:));
tstamptwo = %timestamp(&(2:));

*  Difference between two TimeStamps in ms
/FREE
   &(3:) = %DIFF (tstampone: tstamptwo: *MSECONDS);
/END-FREE
```

Compiler throws warnings: `RNF0580` and `RNF0581`

Comment: I don't understand the question...what IDE are you using?  How does the IDE have parameters?  You need the tstampone and tstamptwo declared as type timestamp..

Comment: I'm using CA Plex. Already found the answer. Posting it.

Comment: Ah now see, if you'd had mentioned Plex I might have remember the answer.  Surprised I didn't recognize the &(3:)  syntax, but then again it's been a few years.  If you're not already a member, I highly recommend joining the  [CA Plex  / 2E user community](https://communities.ca.com/community/ca-plex-ca-2e/overview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
  /FREE
    &(3:) = %DIFF (%TIMESTAMP(&(1:)): %TIMESTAMP(&(2:)): *MS);
  /END-FREE
```

Comment: You might look through the CA Plex community I posted a link to in my other comment.  IIRC,  there were some enhancements a few years ago around the v6 version of Plex in how it dealt with dates (& timestamps?).  I think there was an INI setting added that controlled how dates related code was generated.  May have been something in the MSGF that controlled how the RPGIV compiler was invoked.

Comment: Thanks @Charles for your support. I didn't mention CA Plex because it isn't a common IDE and there was a big chance you didn't know what I was talking about, however, you knew it. I also tried to join CA Plex community but I never get the confirmation e-mail, so I couldn't join, I'll keep trying. Thanks.